# Populate a DropDownList with Users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make my model to associate with a **User** from the Identity system in ASP.NET MVC 5, instead of an **Employee**. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out the magic behind @Html.DropDownList... I'm pulling my hair out. Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    [Display(Name="ID#")]
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public EmployeeViewModel Employee { get; set; }
    public ShopViewModel Shop { get; set; }
    public TotsUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and the TicketController method:

```
// GET: /Ticket/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Ticket ticket = db.Tickets.Find(id);
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        TicketViewModel ticketVM = Mapper.Map(ticket, new TicketViewModel());

        ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeId", "Name", ticketVM.EmployeeId);
        ViewBag.ShopId = new SelectList(db.Shops, "ShopId", "Name", ticketVM.ShopId);
        ViewBag.UserListing = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", ticketVM.UserId);

        return View(ticketVM);
    }
```

The view (the part in question)

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "EmployeeId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "UserId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @* @Html.DropDownList("UserId", String.Empty) *@
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId", @ViewBag.UserListing, null);
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I can't even explain how it even works with **EmployeeId**. This is the way that the scaffold generated it for my original model. It populates `EmployeeId` just fine. Can someone please explain the dark magic going on with the `@Html.DropDownList` helper and explain why I can't get the DropDownList to populate with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to change

`ViewBag.UserListing = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", ticketVM.UserId);`

to

`ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", ticketVM.UserId);`

or change

`@Html.DropDownList("UserId", @ViewBag.UserListing, null);`

to

`@Html.DropDownList("UserId", (SelectList)@ViewBag.UserListing);`

This is incorrect no matter which method you use

`@Html.DropDownList("UserId", @ViewBag.UserListing, null);`

You have to tell the helper what type of object `@ViewBag.UserListing` is. In your case it would be `(SelectList)@ViewBag.UserListing`

Comment: Looks like I was close. I was using the wrong overloaded version of `DropDownList` for starters. Thanks for your time!